# Why does my code show NameError in python when I try to use of OOP and classes?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, subclass

```
def God():
    #code
    class Human:
        def __init__(self):
            pass
    class Man(Human):
        def __init__(self):
            pass       
    class Woman(Human):
        def __init__(self):
            pass   
    a=Man()
    b=Woman()

    return [a.__class__,b.__class__]
```

Why is this code showing NameError?
I am trying to create three classes and return the instances of two classes as an entities in an array
The test code is given below

```
paradise = God()
test.assert_equals(isinstance(paradise[0], Man) , True, "First object are a man")
```

Comment: your indentation is off, fix it please and post the traceback

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. `print(God())` prints `[<class '__main__.God.<locals>.Man'>, <class '__main__.God.<locals>.Woman'>]`

Comment: You aren't returning two instances of the subclasses; you are unnecessarily *creating* two instances, then returning the types of those instances in the list. It's also not clear why you are defining the classes inside the function.

Comment: @chepner Why can I not define classes inside a function? Can you show how to return instances of subclasses without creating it first?

Comment: @Barmar I have added the test code which I am not able to pass with this code.

Comment: @gold_cy Sorry, but I cannot find the indentation error which you are talking about

Comment: @RoundRobin I already fixed it for you. See my first edit.

Comment: A class is not an instance of itself. `paradise[0]` is the class `Man`, not an instance of the class `Man`.

Comment: `Man` and `Woman` are defined locally to the `God()` function, you can't reference it outside the function.

Comment: The classes should just be defined *outside* the function. Otherwise, you are redefining the classes every time you call the function.

Answer (score 1):

`Man` and `Woman` are local variables inside the `God()` function, you can't reference them outside the function. You should take the class definitions out of the function.

And if you want to return instances, don't use `__class__`.

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Man(Human):
    def __init__(self):
        pass   
    
class Woman(Human):
    def __init__(self):
        pass   

def God():
    a=Man()
    b=Woman()

    return [a ,b]
```

Comment: I think the intent is to just return `[a, b]`.